# Worklight 6.1 - App Center Mobile Client error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

I'm currently trying to build the mobile client for IOS. There are 2 issue currently lingering:

1. The mobile client will be used for user to download the app from our test server. When i build, i run the Build Setting and Deploy Target script and tick the checkbox to deploy for another server. However i'm not sure the context path need to be put as what, the current default is /IBMAppCenter
2. When i try run the app center in the XCode simulator, the app center keep running with a loading icon. I check the log and found that it says:

   ERROR: Plugin 'com.ibm.mobile.InstallerPlugin' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin.
   Check your plugin mapping in config.xml

I check my native folder (ipad\native\CordovaLib) and true enough, the CDVPlugin was not in the plugin folder, but when i look into the Classes folder, the header (.h) and implementation (.m) files are there. How should i configure to make it work?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About question 1:

The deploy target is irrelevant. It is only relevant for "normal" Worklight applications that are managed by a Worklight Console (so you must specify on which server your Worklight Console runs). But the Application Center client is not managed by any Worklight Console. All what you do is to build the environment, create the IPA and upload it to the Application Center server. Therefore, please only use the "Build all environments" menu item and ignore anything with deploy target!

See here: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.appadmin.doc%2Fappcenter%2Ft_ac_proj_imp_build.html

About question 2:

The Application Center mobile client for iOS should be in the **iphone** environment, not in the ipad environment. The code in the iphone environment folder should work for ipad as well but you cannot generate an ipad environment for the Application Center client, as well as you cannot delete the iphone environment and regenerated it via File > New > Environment, because when you do that, the libAppCenterInstallerLib.a gets deleted. You must take the project as it was in your original installation.

Please check IBMAppCenter/apps/AppCenter/**iphone**/native/appCenterLib. This should contain subdirectories (for Release, Debug ...) which contain libAppCenterInstallerLib.a. The error message that you see means that it cannot find this library; probably because you deleted the iphone environment or because you attempted to create an ipad environment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to deploy using the iphone environment instance, but when i try to install it in the device, it goes into an infinite loop of installing process..

Comment: Ah found out the issue, is regarding the provisioning profile. Managed to get it working now. Thanks!